# Physical layer services & hardware protocols

Tags: computer-networks

I am searching the content of this topic but I am not sure what should be the content for this topic. This is relate to Computer Network.
My topic is `Physical layer services & hardware protocols.`

What should be content for this topic.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you don't know what your topic is, why are you interested in it? If someone told you to look it up, ask them for guidance.

Comment: I am not getting content for this topic So I am asking this.

Comment: Get the relevant buzzwords or introductory references from your teacher; this is not the place to rehash an entire field.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick answer:

Hardware protocols are at the lowest level of the [Open System Interconnection (OSI) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_1%3a_physical_layer) and are usually a mix of

- hardware specifications (cables, connectors,  signals, ...)
- how data is exchanged between the hardware devices (start of communication, end of communication, data exchange, flow of control, timings, error handling, ...)

Typical examples of hardware protocols are: serial port RS-232, Parallel port IEEE 1284, USB , [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet), bus protocols, ...

Physical layer services are those functions used to correctly implement and manage the communication between devices at the physical layer: e.g. open a port, convert bits to timed signals, change the bit-rate, close a port, send data, multiplexing, flush data,  ...

Comment: Can I consider [List of protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) for 'hardware protocols' and [List of services] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_layer) for `Physical layer services`